# how would I implement a certain instruction in MIPS?

Tags: mips, instruction-set

I need to implement an instruction in MIPS assembly that jumps to a location stored in a register if its value is non-negative; otherwise, it jumps to a location stored in a second register.

I'm having an issue with how to check for negative values in registers and also need help understanding how to implement this.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have in `$t1` the test register (the one pointing to the address to jump if its contents is non-negative), and in `$t2` the register which will hold the address of the jump if `$t1` is negative.

Then, this snippet should do the trick:

```
    bge $t1, $zero, is_positive
    jr $t2
is_positive:
    jr $t1
```

The first instruction branches to is_positive if `$t0` is non-negative. The instruction at that label jumps to the address given by `$t1`. If the branch is not taken (i.e. `$t`0 is negative), then the following instruction is executed which will jump to the address given by `$t2`.

Comment: i need to implement it as a single instruction

Comment: There is no instruction in MIPS ISA which does what you want. You can emulate it for example with the snippet given in the answer.